# Android StatuBar overlay

Tags: android, overlay, material-design, statusbar

I have developed a simple Android application for reading PDF books. I started with developing about one year ago, so I was targeting SDK version 18. Now it is needed to start using a Material design, so I set my `targetSdkVersion` to 22. 
After some customizations with Toolbar, I have a problem with fullscreen mode.
In the first picture, there is everything fine. The fullscreen mode is not activated.

[image: The first picture. Fullscreen is not activated and everything looks fine.]

In the second picture, there you can see a white row at the top of the screen. This is ugly and I need to remove it.

[image]

When I was targeting SDK version 18, it was fine, because I have set, that StatusBar will overlay content of whole Activity. Now, it seems that it does not work.

In my activity, there I have these lines:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Window window = getWindow();                
    supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_OVERSCAN);

    // some other code is here...        
}
```

Code for switching between fullscreen mode follows:

```
protected void fullscreenOn() {
    if (mActivity != null && !mSearchModeOn) {
        Window window = mActivity.getWindow();
        View decorView = window.getDecorView();
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View
                    .SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | View
                    .SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
        } else {
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN);
            mActionBar.hide();
        }

        bottomBarsLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mIsFullscreenOn = true;
    }
}

protected void fullscreenOff() {
    if (mActivity != null) {
        Window window = mActivity.getWindow();
        View decorView = window.getDecorView();
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(mNormalUIVisibility);
        } else {
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN);
            mActionBar.show();
        }

        bottomBarsLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mIsFullscreenOn = false;
    }
}
```

Almost everything works fine. There is only one problem here - the problem with white row at the top of the screen.
Can you help me please, how can I make the StatusBar overlaying? It means, that content of activity will cover whole screen. 
I know that I can change the color of StatusBar with `android:colorPrimaryDark`, but I do not want to do that.

**UPDATE**

Note, that my Activity extends `AppCompatActivity`.

**UPDATE 2**

Layout of my activity looks like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <include
            layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

        <include layout="@layout/fragment_single_root"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/menu_list"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Toolbar is here:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:elevation="4dp"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
/>
```

And layout of my fragment, which is attached to activity, follows:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.radaee.reader.PDFReader
    android:id="@+id/pdf_reader_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/frame_layout_bottom_bars"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/read_book_bottom_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/bottomBarBackground"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/img_view_read_book_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/title_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:background="?attr/imgBtnContent" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seek_bar_read_book_listing"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/text_view_read_book_pages"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/img_view_read_book_content"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/text_view_read_book_pages"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="?attr/simpleFontColor"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/read_book_search_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="?attr/bottomBarBackground"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:weightSum="5">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_view_search_prev"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="?attr/imgPrevSearchResult" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_search_info"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:textColor="?attr/simpleFontColor"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="Test" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/pdf_search_progress_bar"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_view_search_next"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="?attr/imgNextSearchResult" />
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative_layout_custom_preview_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <cz.project.base.view.TwoWayView
        android:id="@+id/two_way_view_page_preview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

set `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"`, that will avoid padding on top and on the bottom.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But now the action bar is overlayed by status bar. How can I solve it, man?

Answer (score 0):

Move

```
Window window = getWindow();                
supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_OVERSCAN);
```

before

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

Or you can use this :

```
this.supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            Window w = getWindow(); // in Activity's onCreate() for instance
            w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
}
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

For translucent navigation and system bar with same color of toolbar.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it, but it doesn't work. I see the exactly same behavior.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't see the difference. I see the same behavior.

Comment: Can you post XML layout?

Comment: Sure. Do you want to see the layout from activity, where the reading fragment is attached, or layout of this attached fragment?

Answer (score 0):

Use this style and set it for your activity -

```
<style name="FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```